# HOG vector size and dimension

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I am having problem to understand about size of HOG feature vector...

**scene:** I took a 286x286 image.Then I calculated HOG for 8x8 patch each.Mean I got 8x8x2=128 numbers represented by a 9 bin histogram for each patch.so can I say this 9 bin histogram as a 9 dimensional vector?.After,total number of patch to estimate HOG in whole image was approx. 1225(*since I have square matrix I estimated total patch by squaring(286/8)=35)*).I iterated 1225 patches and calculated 9 bin histogram for each.*(I didn't applied 16x16 block normalization)* After that concatenating all vector together I obtained 1225x9=11,025 sized HOG of whole image.

**question:**

*1.Then is is right to say I obtained 11,025 dimension of an HOG vector in given image?*

*2.Am I going in right direction?(if I opt for classification via neural network)*

*3.Is this concatenated HOG feature can directly feeded to PCA for dimension reduction?or need further more preprocessing?(in genral not in advance)*

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Probably not. What are you trying to do? For example, if you are doing classification, you should use bag-of-words (actually, you should stop using HOG and try deep learning). If you are doing image retrieval/matching, you should compute HOG feature for local patches.
3. You can almost always use PCA for dimensionality reduction for your features, even for 128 dimensional SIFT.

Comment: I will feed these reduced feature to Neural Networks....currently I don't have any plan regarding deep neural net....first I would like to play with neural net(backProp)..then is it correct or not...features will be reduced via PCA then fed to network for classification purpose..